# Cmake Couldn't find boost

Tags: cmake, boost

I ran `cmake` to compile BLender then I got this error:

```
Couldnt find boost
```

I have already installed `libboost* 1.53 dev`

How can Cmake find boost? What should I add to `Cmakelist.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

You may be missing some dependencies required for installing Blender. The libboost* dependencies for Blender in Ubuntu 13.04, 13.10 and 14.04 are as follows<sup>1</sup>:

libboost-filesystem
  libboost-locale
  libboost-system
  libboost-thread

The libboost* dependencies for Blender in Ubuntu 16.04 are as follows:

libboost-filesystem1.58.0
  libboost-locale1.58.0
  libboost-system1.58.0
  libboost-thread1.58.0

The libboost* dependencies for Blender in Ubuntu 18.04 are as follows:

libboost-locale1.65.1
  libboost-system1.65.1
  libboost-thread1.65.1

The libboost* dependencies for Blender in Ubuntu 18.10, 19.04 and 19.10  are as follows:

libboost-locale1.67.0
  libboost-system1.67.0
  libboost-thread1.67.0

The libboost* dependencies for Blender in Ubuntu 20.04  are as follows:

libboost-locale1.71.0
  libboost-thread1.71.0

All of these dependencies can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. Check at the link mentioned above to make sure that the libboost* versions selected are at least as current as the versions specified in the link, as there are multiple versions of libboost* available in the default Ubuntu repositories (all of which are from the universe repository).

<sup>1</sup><sub>Blender in Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10 does not require these four libboost packages.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes in your CMakeLists.txt

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
```

in CMakeLists.txt it will work. For me, it worked.