# cmake can't find boost

Tags: cmake, boost

I'm trying to compile the software "[TrinityCore](https://www.trinitycore.org/)". The process is explained quite thoroughly here: https://trinitycore.atlassian.net/wiki/display/tc/Linux+Core+Installation

After installing the dependencies, which include `libboost-all-dev` I was using `cmake` as explained. It stopped configuring when looking for some boost libraries (see below).

The strange thing is that I installed the required packages and there are directories in

```
/usr/include
```

that match the names of the missing libraries.

I also tried the solution here: [Cmake Couldn't find boost](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354605/cmake-couldnt-find-boost) but unfortunately without success.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in regards!

Here the exact error message:

```
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.58.0

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_filesystem
          boost_thread
          boost_program_options
          boost_iostreams

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.  If you still have problems search on forum for TCE00020.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
```

Comment: `/usr/include` contains *headers* not libraries - did you check that the corresponding **static** libraries e.g. `libboost_system.a` exist (on 64-bit systems, they should be in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ I think). OTOH I'm not sure why it would be looking for static libs - iirc the cmake defaults to dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, only reinstalling Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 helped. Then, I didn't install

`libboost-all-dev`

but only the packages required by Trinitycore. Now

`make`

is runnig after cmake without any problems.

By adding the options

```
-DBoost_<missing package>_RELEASE=/usr/include/boost/<missing package>/
```

cmake can find it. Odd, because these are just subdirectories of

```
/usr/include/boost
```

which was already found by cmake.

Comment: Okay, this doesn't seem to really help since at the end of the configuring it says:
WARNING: Target "common" requests linking to directory "/usr/include/boost/system".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.